# React Router v6 Private Route and passing state between components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am creating a React app and wanted to use Private Routes to protect my pages. Below is my App.js

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ setUserEmail, setUserName, setUserRole, redirectPath = '/login' }) => {
  const url = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_HOST + USER_URI;
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", url, false); // `false` makes the request synchronous
  request.withCredentials = true;
  request.send(null);

  if (request.status === 200) {
    const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText)
    console.log(data)
    setUserEmail(data.email);
    setUserName(data.name);
    setUserRole(data.role);
  }
  else if (request.status === 403 || request.status === 401) {
    return <Navigate to={redirectPath} replace />;
  }
  else {
    return <Navigate to={redirectPath} replace />;
  }
  return <Outlet />;
};

function App() {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
  const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState("");
  const [userRole, setUserRole] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoute setUserEmail={setUserEmail} setUserRole={setUserRole} setUserName={setUserName} />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home userEmail={userEmail} userName={userName} userRole={userRole} />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now as you see, to check auth, I am hitting an API request, if it fails, I redirect to login page. This is working fine. Now if it succeeds, I am setting user details, and then passing those to other components. This is not working. I see empty text when I try to access these properties in other components.

This is my Home.js

```
function Home(userName="defaultUser", userRole="defaultRole", userEmail="defaultEmail") {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            Hello!
            <p>
                {userRole} {userName} {userEmail}
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Also, I wanted to know if this is the best way to Private Route based on an API response and pass response items to corresponding components. Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Regarding the `PrivateRoute` component, no, that is not the best way as it is making the network call and enqueued state updates as unintentional side-effects. The function body is is synchronous, so it won't/can't wait for the request to resolve when it renders anyway. Use the `useEffect` hook to issue the side-effect ***intentionally***, and implement some local state to track/await the response. See my answer [here](/a/66289280/8690857) for a more conventional route protection implementation.

Answer (score 1):

React components are passed a single props object.

Given:

```
<Home userEmail={userEmail} userName={userName} userRole={userRole} />
```

The `Home` component should destructure the props from the single props object.

```
function Home({
  userName = "defaultUser",
  userRole = "defaultRole",
  userEmail = "defaultEmail"
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      Hello!
      <p>{userRole} {userName} {userEmail}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```